# Do material snackbar observables complete?

Tags: angular, angular-material, observable

I'm using Angular Material v8.2.3 and the [snackbar](https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/overview#opening-a-snack-bar) exposes observables including `onAction` which can be subscribed.

Do they need to be unsubscribed or will they complete when the snackbar is dismissed?

Comment: It will be completed after dismissed. check the source code :https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/snack-bar/snack-bar-ref.ts#L71

Comment: @Chellappan TY. feel free to post as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per material source code, It will be completed when the dismissAction triggered.

```
 dismissWithAction(): void {
    if (!this._onAction.closed) {
      this._dismissedByAction = true;
      this._onAction.next();
      this._onAction.complete();
    }
  }
```

[Check This](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/snack-bar/snack-bar-ref.ts#L71)